# Using a Razer keyboard's WinKey as the Command key for a Mac

Tags: macos, windows-key, razer-keyboard

I recently bought a MacBook and I'm trying to use it with my Razer Lycosa keyboard. OS X doesn't seem to be able to map — or even detect — the Windows key at all. I'd like to use it as the Command key. Is this possible?

Comment: I own that keyboard and I know there is a way to disable the windows key so make sure you have not done that. Something like holding windows then taping the razer symbol

Comment: No, I tried that. I also tried drivers for other Razer keyboards without any success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes the "gaming mode" gets activated on the Lycosa, which locks <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> (<kbd>command key</kbd> on Macs).

Instructions on how to disable gaming mode are available on the [Razer site](http://help.razersupport.com/us-en/resolution.asp?sid=183853101223066249072112&pid=1622&pnm=Razer+Lycosa&seid=400002708&pos=Windows&top=&rid=26479)

> You can activate the gaming mode for Razer Lycosa by pressing and
>   holding the Razer Logo at the TouchPanel and then pressing the Windows
>   key. This will deactivate the Windows key. To reactivate the Windows
>   key you just need to press and hold the Razer Logo at the TouchPanel
>   and then press the Windows key again.

Comment: You win internet, sir! Thanks a lot :) I wasn't aware this option was there.

Comment: You're most welcome :) I think you should tag this post with Lycosa, Razer and Mac as well to make it easier to find.

Comment: Added Razer keyword, should be enough. It's general issue, not Mac specific. I was dealing with it on Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the "Modifier keys" in Keyboard prefs->Keyboard tab?

Comment: Yes, but the windows key doesn't seem to be even detected by system.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure then. I use a PC keyboard on my Mac, and the Windows key is detected as an alt key. I use the prefs to swap alt and cmd. There seems to be a number of people asking about using Razer keyboards on Macs on the web. Maybe they don't use the normal key mappings and rely on their drivers on Windows. You might have some luck with a keyboard utility like Keyboard Maestro.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change the alt key to command and windows key to option
like this.
It may not feel right at the start but they are taking the positions of the command and option keys of a magic keyboard

[image]